# Gulp переписал с gulp.parallel, но все равно выдает ошибку

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Было так

```
gulp.task('live-server', function () {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './dist',
      directory: true
    },
    notify: false
  });

  gulp.watch('**/*', {
    cwd: './dist/'
  }, browserSync.reload);
});


gulp.task('mdb-go', function () {
  gulp.start('live-server');
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['css-compile']);
  gulp.watch(['dist/css/*.css', '!dist/css/*.min.css'], ['css-minify']);
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['js-build']);
  gulp.watch(['dist/js/*.js', '!dist/js/*.min.js'], ['js-minify']);
  gulp.watch('**/*', {
    cwd: './img/'
  }, ['img-compression']);
});
```

Переписал так

```
    gulp.task('live-server', function () {
      browserSync.init({
        server: {
          baseDir: './dist',
          directory: true
        },
        notify: false
      });

      gulp.watch('**/*', {
        cwd: './dist/'
      }, browserSync.reload);
    });

    // Watch on everything
    gulp.task('mdb-go', function () {
  gulp.start('live-server');
  gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', gulp.parallel('css-compile'));
  gulp.watch(['dist/css/*.css', '!dist/css/*.min.css'], gulp.parallel('css-minify'));
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', gulp.parallel('js-build'));
  gulp.watch(['dist/js/*.js', '!dist/js/*.min.js'], gulp.parallel('js-minify'));
  gulp.watch('**/*', {
    cwd: './img/'
  }, ['img-compression']);
});
```

Но ошибка осталась
[14:12:41] Task never defined: default
[14:12:41] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks

Comment: добавьте `gulp.task('default', ['mdb-go']);`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по выводу консоли, вы запускаете сборку командой просто командой `gulp`, без указания таска который надо выполнить. В этом случае, gulp пытается запустить дефолтный таск с именем **default**. Но у вас его нет, о чем она вам, собственно, и сообщает.

Вам надо просто запустить указать gulp имя таска. Судя по вашему конфигу для запуска таска с вотчерами вам надо выполнить такую команду: `gulp mdb-go`